# Unanswered questions are all answers

Tags: support

If I click on the "Unanswered" button I see a bunch of questions, all or most of which have been answered.  ?

Answer (score 6):

[The `Unanswered Questions` tab shows questions that have no answers with a positive score nor an accepted answer. (That includes questions with no answers at all.)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/18871/272257)

See also: [OK, Now Define “Answered”](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2008/09/ok-now-define-answered/)